# Wordpress Url setting

Tags: plugins

AOA,
I want to set my urls in wordpress something like this.

http://www.digitalspinners.no/wp_mahasib/21-05-2012/abbotabad/page1

http://www.digitalspinners.no/wp_mahasib/21-05-2012/lahore/page1

but wordpress adds a dash and number to the end of url like this

wp_mahasib/21-05-2012/lahore/page1-2

url explanation is : date/category/postname

Any suggestion or improvement will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Page in this case is post name or number of page of tha same post? If it's just post name, as i can gues from your permalink structure - then wp should'n add any numbers, unless there is already post with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the slug "page" is already being associated with some other post. 
So Make sure there is not post in trash which is capturing the slug.

Comment: please don't sign off